# During build with maven tables are not generated. What am I missing in my configuration?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, maven, datasource

During the maven build, the application is deployed successfully but tables are not created in the database based on models with the @entity annotation that are in the app.

I got a multi-module maven project, Postgres database and Wildfly 16.0.0.Final. In Wildfly, I have created datasource and connected it with the database. I tested a connection and it works. During Maven build application is properly deployed without any errors but tables are not created. I was trying to use different dialect, change hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto values, change my classes with @entity annotation to be as basic as possible to see if the error is somewhere there but still, no tables are created and no errors displayed.

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <!-- Define persistence unit -->
    <persistence-unit name="event-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:/eventDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>com.event.model.baseEntity</class>
        <class>com.event.model.Event</class>
        <class>com.event.model.Group</class>
        <class>com.event.model.User</class>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/jpa/eventEMF"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml of module that stores models for which I'm trying to generate tables:

```
 <artifactId>Models</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Example of a model for which I want to generate a table in database:

```
@Entity
public class Group extends baseEntity {

    String name;
    String description;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected User User;



}
```

base class that provides id and timestamp to each of my models:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@AttributeOverrides(value = @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")))
public class baseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    UUID ID;

    @Version
    int version;



    public UUID getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(UUID ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();

    public baseEntity() {
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(LocalDateTime timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void updateTimestamp() {
        timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to generate all tables in the database during maven build based on annotation's used. Is there any error in my configuration/code, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is `persistence.xml` in right directory? If you replace it with invalid file(random characters)  does Wildfly complain about it? What error you get when your code tries to do operations (find/persist) on `Group`, when tables are not created yet? What artifact type are you deploying, `.war` or `.ear`?

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Persistence.xml is in the correct directory:  this is the path to the models: eventApplication/Models/src/main/java/com/event/model/Group.java and here is the path for persistence.xml: eventApplication/Models/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml. When it comes to replacing persistence.xml I  typed some random words in persistence.xml and there was no error during deploy but now I noticed that application is deployed as .jar not .ear so I thinks that's may be a reason

Comment: I have fixed type of a deploy by adding <packaging>ear</packaging> inside pom.xml but it did not solve the issue described in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it appears that the application was not properly deployed. I had to change the deployment type from .jar to .ear. After that, there was a problem with spring security which was solved. Now application deploys properly and creates tables. Special thanks to user158037 as His question about deployment type led me to the solution.